# How can I run a selenium test from an electron app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, electron

I want to be able to start my selenium web bot from an electron GUI...I've already coded the selenium portion but I'm unsure on how I'd be able to programmatically start the the selenium "test" through my electron app.